# How to `add_done_callback` after several futures are finished?

Tags: python, concurrency, concurrent.futures

I would like to add a callback after several [`concurrent.futures.Future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future)s. Is this possible?

```
import time
import random
import threading
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, wait


def random_duration_action():
    s = 1 + random.random() * 10
    print("Thread", threading.get_ident(), "will sleep for", s, "seconds")
    time.sleep(s)
    return s


def all_is_done(futures):
    print("We're all done: ", [f.result() for f in futures])


pool = ThreadPoolExecutor()
f1 = pool.submit(random_duration_action)
f2 = pool.submit(random_duration_action)

# Is there a convenient function like this one?
group_of_futures([f1, f2]).add_done_callback(all_is_done)

print("Now waiting...")
pool.shutdown()
```

The best I could come up with is this:

```
def wait_for_all(futures):
    wait(futures)
    return futures


def all_is_done(future):
    print("We're all done: ", [f.result() for f in future.result()])


pool = ThreadPoolExecutor()
f1 = pool.submit(random_duration_action)
f2 = pool.submit(random_duration_action)
f3 = pool.submit(wait_for_all, [f1, f2])
f3.add_done_callback(all_is_done)
```

Isn't there a function in the standard lib that accomplishes this better and that I could not find?